# How to use . in re.match()

Tags: python, python-re

I want to make a basic chat program using socket and I want to ask client the address. The address format is `IP port`. IP is like `num.num.num.num` and port is just a 4 or 5 digit number. I want to use `re.match` function to check if inpu is a valid address. How can I use . as character?

Comment: you need to escape it, using the char \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use . as a character in regular expressions, escape it with a backslash like this: `\.`

So, to match an IP port address, you could use:

```
[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*
```

Edit: As suggested in the comments, for more accurate IPv4 matching you would need to limit the number of digits in each number, like this:

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Comment: This will also match `9999.9999.9999.9999` which is not a valid IP address. Actually it'll match any Also it may be better to use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

Comment: I think this will not be problem because it will not connect a ip like 9999.9999.9999.9999 and just say did not connect.

Comment: @tayken, that's a good point. The question is focused on using . as a regex character, but your suggestion is a great improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You escape things with `\` so you search for `\.`.

There is a bit more to checking IP addresses though. so there are multiple options depending on how exact vs complicated you want your regex to be. [This site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html) has more information.